# Pdfmake background color to pages

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

How to set background color to pages in pdfmake. I tried using the fillColor but it doesn't work. It's working fine for coloumns and tables. But i want to change the background color for the document.

Answer (score 0):

Pdfmake does not provide a direct solution for setting background color for pages.

However, you can use a canvas to draw stuff on the screen.

```js
// Page dimensions for A4
const pdfWidth = 595.35;
const pdfHeight = 841.995;

const docDefinition = {
  pageSize: {
    width: pdfWidth,
    height: pdfHeight,
  },
  content: [
    'This is a standard paragraph, using default style',
    { text: 'This paragraph will have a bigger font', fontSize: 15, pageBreak: 'after' },
    {
      text: [
        'This paragraph is defined as an array of elements to make it possible to ',
        { text: 'restyle part of it and make it bigger ', fontSize: 15 },
        'than the rest.'
      ],
    },
  ],
  background: (idx) => ({ // <- this part
    canvas: [{
      type: 'rect',
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: pdfWidth,
      h: pdfHeight,
      color: ['red', 'blue'][idx - 1],
    }]
  })
};

pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
```

This method allows you to set the background color based on page numbers.

You will notice that we have set hardcoded values for page dimensions and canvas dimensions. As we need to explicitly provide the page dimensions, we cannot use directly set the page sizes using **A1**, **A2**, etc.

To get the dimensions of page based on paper size, refer to [this github code](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/src/standardPageSizes.js) that pdfmake uses to set the values.